# OOB pairing without NFC

Tags: security, bluetooth

I'm building a medical device with NFC capability. This medical device can be connected to a mobile phone/tablet over Bluetooth and operated by an App.

During the pairing process, the App asks the user to put the mobile phone on the device's NFC spot in order to exchange the key for OOB pairing. Every time a new measurements is taken (we are talking about a medical device), a new key must be generated, and so a scan on the NFC tag is required.

But what if the mobile phone/tablet running the App does not have NFC? I tought that I could print a QR code on the chassis of the device, but it's quite frustrating to have to scan the QR code many times a day.

Is there another way to accomplish OOB pairing without Bluetooth, giving the fact that the device does not have a button or a screen?

Comment: Why do you have to re-pair for every reading? Is it a different phone for each reading?